# simultaneously groupby of pandas rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that I'd like to find the mean value over 2D groups (groupby columns **and** rows) rather than the usual 1D (groupby columns **or** rows) groups.
For the above simple function (mean), I have found a simple solution, to take the mean values over rows groups and then take the mean over columns.

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(12345)
names = ['A'] * 2 + ['B'] *3
mat = rng.random((5, 5))
mat = mat + mat.T # simetry of diatnce matrix
np.fill_diagonal(mat, 0) # diagonal values are equal zero in distance matrix
df = pd.DataFrame(mat, index=names, columns=names)
print(df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean().groupby(level=0, axis=0).mean())
```

output:

```
          A         B
A  0.324786  1.114762
B  1.114762  0.419920
```

However, I was wondering whether a more general solution exists, that would be applicable for more complicated functions that should be calculated directly over the 2D sub dataframes, and can't be split up into two stages like the mean. For example, let's say I would like to find the average value of the upper triangular of the 2D sub-dataframes if *column name* is  equal to *row name*, conceptually this should look like this (without taking advantage of *pandas* *groupby*):

```py
def triu_mean(mat):
    res = mat[np.triu_indices(len(mat), 1)].mean()
    return res
df_out = pd.DataFrame(index=df.columns.unique(), columns=df.columns.unique())
for col_name in df.columns.unique():
    for row_name in df.index.unique():
        sub_df = df.loc[row_name, col_name]
        if col_name == row_name:
            df_out.loc[row_name, col_name] = triu_mean(sub_df.values)
        else:
             df_out.loc[row_name, col_name] = sub_df.values.mean()
print(df_out)
```

output:

```
          A        B
A  0.649572  1.11476
B   1.11476  0.62988
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your method is incorrect, as you cannot calculate the mean of a combination by calculating the mean successively. This works by chance here as there is no missing data.

Instead, you can `stack` first, `groupby` both levels to apply your transformation, then `unstack`:

```
(df.stack()              # move columns to index
   .groupby(level=[0,1]) # groupby + transform
   .mean()
   .unstack()            # move back to columns
)
```

output:

```
          A         B
A -0.567193 -0.358015
B  0.844443 -0.053647
```

#### demonstration of the incorrect value with OP's method:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5,5),
                   index=names,
                   columns=names)
        .replace(4, float('nan'))  ## introducing a missing value
     )
```

```
          A         A         B         B         B
A       NaN  1.263728 -0.870662 -0.259173 -0.075343
A -0.740885 -1.367793  0.648893  0.361058 -1.952863
B  2.347410  0.968497 -0.759387  0.902198 -0.466953
B -0.060690  0.788844 -1.256668  0.575858  1.398979
B  1.322298 -0.299699  0.902919 -1.621583 -0.158189
```

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean().groupby(level=0, axis=0).mean()
          A         B
A  0.104695 -0.358015   ### A/A is incorrect
B  0.844443 -0.053647

>>> df.stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).mean().unstack()
          A         B
A -0.281650 -0.358015
B  0.844443 -0.053647
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that issue, in my case I have a full dataframe without missing data

Comment: @itamarkanter so this solution works for you?

Comment: Yes, for the current problem. But actually, I'm looking for a solution that will also preserve the 2D shape of the sub-dataframe. Do you have any idea how to do this? my actual dataframe is a distance matrix and I'm trying to find the average distance between groups (e.g. A-A distance), but for this value to be valid I have to omit the diagonal values

Comment: @itamarkanter can you provide an example?